# Why Collate keyword is Giving error?

Tags: mysql, sql

Collate is a valid keyword in MySQL but when I use it in the following query, it gives me error of unrecognized keyword...

```
SELECT Image FROM Images WHERE COLLATE utf_bin urdu = 'اِس';
```

What to do ?

Comment: `WHERE column-name COLLATE collation-name = ...`

Comment: It is giving the same error...:/

Comment: Which MySQL version are you using?

Comment: here is the version number: 10.1.21

Answer (score -1):

SELECT Column1
FROM Table1
WHERE Column1 COLLATE utf_bin urdu = 'اِس'

Answer (score -1):

**Final code:**

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE Images_Urdu
(
    Image BLOB
    ,Urdu VARCHAR(20) CHARACTER SET utf8
);
INSERT INTO Images_Urdu(Urdu) values('English'), ('ありがとうございます'), ('اِس');
SELECT * FROM Images_Urdu WHERE  Urdu = 'اِس' COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci;
```

1. Consider using `utf8` as character set for the Urdu column. It will enable to insert the non-english character.
2. For Urdu language the collation is `utf8_unicode_ci`
3. In the WHERE clause, COLLATE keyword will come after the column name(Urdu)

[rextester link](http://rextester.com/TAG3897)

*Note: I have not inserted any images so it will return null for the Image column*

Comment: Brother please see the tag, I need it for mysql